# Chapter number is string in TOC and numeral in chapter header (memoir)?

Tags: chapters, memoir

My MWE formats the chapter number as a string in my TOC like I want, but it also changes the chapter number to a string in the chapter header. I want it to be a string in my TOC and a numeral in my chapter header as I marked up. I'd also like to lose the "Chapter" word in my chapter header is I marked up?

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\ordinal\relax

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering\HUGE\textit{Contents}}

% Chapter
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfillnum}[1]{\hspace*{10pt}\huge#1\cftparfillskip\par}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{}
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\hfil\Large\emph{#1}\hfil\strut\huge\par\nopagebreak\hfil}

% Document
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{The First Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new chapter style.

TOC style

[image: t]

Chapter style

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\ordinal\relax

\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering\HUGE\textit{Contents}}

% Chapter
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\let\oldthechapter\thechapter % added <<<<<
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfillnum}[1]{\hspace*{10pt}\huge#1\cftparfillskip\par}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{}
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\hfil\Large\emph{#1}\hfil\strut\huge\par\nopagebreak\hfil}

%*********************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makechapterstyle{centerlike}{% new chapter heading style
    \chapterstyle{default}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\centering}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \oldthechapter}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\centering \chaptitlefont ##1\par}
    \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\vskip\afterchapskip}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{ \vphantom{\chapnumfont \textit{9}}\afterchapternum} 
}
\chapterstyle{centerlike}% use this style
%***********************************************

% Document
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents*
    \chapter{The First Chapter}
\end{document}
```